# Getting an rid after executing a command in OrientDB javascript function

Tags: javascript, orientdb

I'd like to get a newly created record id after executing a command on a non-transactional graph database in OrientDB's function. For instance,

```
var gdb = orient.getGraphNoTx();

var v = gdb.command("sql", "create vertex TestV set time = ?, note = ?", [(new Date().getTime()), 'note']);

//how do i refer to v.rid after creation?

return true;
```

I tried all different options like, `v.rid`, `v['@rid']`, `v.field('rid')`, etc. I am not even sure what type of object is returned from the `gdb.command()`.

What I know so far is that the type of returned value v is object. v.toString() does not provide any valuable insight on it though.

Any ideas?

Comment: I got a workaround, but that's not what I am looking for. Basically the trick is to convert object to string (you will get something like "v(TestV)[#13:1]") and then truncate unnecessary content leaving just the RID. This works for now giving me id, but i do need an access to the object itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var gdb = orient.getGraphNoTx();

var v = gdb.command("sql", "create vertex TestV set time = ?, note = ?", [(new Date().getTime()), 'note']);

print(v.getRecord().field('@rid'));

return true;
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot for that. Is there any documentation which provides such insights in OrientDB functions?

Comment: No problem @AVK. I don't know, but I'm afraid that there isn't.
I just remember seeing it somewhere.

Comment: Pity. Well, hope they have to make on up some day

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with the Java API, but it's quite similar (or even   equal)

Comment: Oh my. I didnt even think about looking into Java API for that. +1 for great suggestion

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to get `@rid` as string from query

```js
var g=orient.getGraph();
var result=g.command('sql',"SELECT FROM something WHERE something=something");
var index=0;
var rid=result[index].getId().toString();
//rid is now string like #12:3456
// you can iterate through result to get all @rid's
```